# How can I launch an application through Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am still new to using Visual Studio, any windows programming really, and I am trying to make an application Launcher for Microsoft Office applications. I have already made the interface but dont know how to make the buttons actually launch the programs. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `System.Diagnostics` namespace to your project and use its `Process.Start` function to start an external application and for closing a process you can use `Process.Close` function, save your started process in a variable and close it when ever you want: like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    // ... Open specified Word file.
    OpenMicrosoftWord(@"C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Gears.docx");
}
public Process myProcess;
static void OpenMicrosoftWord(string file)
{
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE";
   //If skip this line, you'll have an open MS Word with no specific file loaded
   startInfo.Arguments = file;
   myProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
}
static void CloseMicrosoftWord()
{
   myProcess.Close();
}
```

for more information check below links

[Process.Start Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process)

[Using Diagnostics.Process to start an external application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4272/Using-Diagnostics-Process-to-start-an-external-app)

[Process.Close Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: so to make it open a specific file using MS Word i would add that name instead of "file"?

Comment: @JoshColley,If you need to load the app with a specific file you need to provide full address as `file` argument.

Comment: cool, thanks. Also... what if I want to open Sway? It is a Windows Store App and i do not know what it is called. And I have a checkbox that I want to toggle if the application closes after a button is pressed aswell as a button that will just close the app without needing that checkbox selected.can you help?

Comment: @JoshColley,can you find Sway.exe full path from shortcut or somthing?if so, use that path as `startInfo.FileName` and `Process.Start` will open it for you,for closing a process I'll update the answer,hope that helps.

Comment: Sway is an app from the Microsoft store and the store staves all of its apps to a folder that you cant actually open (even with admin). and there are no shortcuts to the app.

Comment: @JoshColley,try this `Process.Start("sway://");` if you didn't success,see [this link](http://www.itsjustwhatever.com/2012/12/22/metro-app-names-the-easy-way/) that shows you how to find your app name,the name you are looking for is in description part.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get it working thqnks to that article. I needed to use "ms-sway://"